# How to make full width image responsive? (no scale / stretch)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

So I've learned about responsive design, and seems pretty straightforward. However, there is one thing I do not understand. I have a big fullwidth image in the center of my homepage. It has a certain size, and CSS seems to require the size in pixels - if I type in % it does not show.

So for now I have

```
.picture-main {
    /*background-color: gray;*/
    background-image: url("./images/homepage_main_picture.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;

    padding-right: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}
```

However, if I change the size of my browser window in order to check responsiveness, it will just scale & stretch it accordingly and the image will be distorted, looking horrible. Does anybody have a solution?

PS: note that other answers here on stackoverflow do not address my question, or at least so I believe. e.g.[this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357609/how-to-make-a-full-width-image-responsive) which is also entitled "how-to-make-a-full-width-image-responsive". - maybe I phrased my question wrongly then?

Comment: Simply use `background-size: cover;` and don't use `;;` in CSS

Comment: Why do you mark this as a duplicate when I explicitly point out that I did not find this on here and the question I linked to is different? The double ; was an error in my stackoverflow post, not in the code.The background-size cover does not fix the issue that it stretches and looks strange depending on the browser window size.

Comment: Sorry, seems I'm missing something. Reopened...

Comment: thanks. i've removed the spelling errors and updated the post now.

Comment: If you want the element at 250px height than you should use either `background-size: cover;` (to cover the entire element) or `background-size: contain;` (which will also keep the image in it's aspect-ratio **but without cut-outs**)

Comment: Responsivnes is about scaling of things. Without scaling it can't be responsive :P

Comment: @GeorgeWelder I'm sorry but there is no way to get a streched image if you are using `background-size: cover;`

Comment: I think it is because you are adding responsivnes to the image holding item and the background-image itself => double responsivnes => destruction

Comment: @ed1nh0 You are right, I must have done something wrong before. it works now, when it gets too big  it just zooms in more. This seems to be the best option. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `background-size: contain;` that way the background image will keep it's proportions.

```css
.picture-main {
  background: url("//placehold.it/500x300/cf5") no-repeat 50%;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.contain{
  background-size: contain;
}
.cover{
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
Example using background-size: contain
<div class="picture-main contain"></div>

Example using background-size: cover
<div class="picture-main cover"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to help me! I just tried it, but this removes the full width of the image. so I have borders on each side now.

Answer (score -1):

One way to go about this would be to set the height of the element as a proportion of the width.

E.g.:

1) So the width of the element is 100% of the viewport width.

2) If the original image is half as high as it is wide, you can set the height of the element to half the width of the viewport.

```
.picture-main {
height:50vw;
}
```

1 vw = 1procent of the Viewport Width. 50vw = 50% of viewport width.

This will give the element the correct size and proportions.
"background-size:cover;" will then ensure that the background fills it out.